# C++ vcproj OutputDirectory macros

Tags: c++, vcproj

In vcproj file i have

```
<Configuration
            Name="Release|Win32"
            OutputDirectory=".\Release"
...
>
```

What is `.\Release` it is some kind of macros? In what settings is it indicated? How setup him?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking? Its a simple directory path, you can put macros in but there aren't any in your current setting. You can change them by using the appropriate property editor in visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a very old version of VC++, but you did not specify which. The (not so) new MSBuild project files have the extension vcxproj and have a different format:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
    <OutDir>.\Release</OutDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Nevertheless, you make these changes from the Project properties. By default, the output directory is `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\` in which case the `<OutDir>` setting is missing. You can, however, explicitly set a different output directory.

I know this refers to the MSBuild project format but these are handled similarly in older versions that were using VSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

`.\Release` is output directory name. Whenever you build your project compiler will create folder `Release` in the current directory and output will copy to that directory.